# Python 3.x runs in IDLE but has issues in Pycharm

Tags: debugging, random, import, pycharm, python-idle

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Python. 
I've been teaching myself Python 3 for the last couple of weeks using IDLE to create my code which has been working great. I recently decided to download and install the community version of PyCharm. Here's my issue...

I've been using the `import random` and `random.randint()` command to generate numbers. When I opened my last Python project, which worked fine in IDLE, into PyCharm and tried to run it, it gave me back two errors.

When I use the "Debug" command in PyCharm, the program runs fine but when I use the "Run" function it gives me two errors. 
Here's my code:

```
import random

# Megamillion Generator
def mega():
    s = []
    a = random.randint(start, finish)
    b = random.randint(start, finish)
    c = random.randint(start, finish)
    d = random.randint(start, finish)
    e = random.randint(start, finish)
    s.append(a)
    s.append(b)
    s.append(c)
    s.append(d)
    s.append(e)
    s.sort()
    if x < 10:
        print("Random ", str(i), " ", end="")
        print(s)
        print("Sorted ", end="")
        print(end="  ")
        print(s)
    else:
        print("Random", str(i), end="")
        print(s)
        s.sort()
        print("Sorted ", end="")
        print(end="")
        print(s)
    return s

    # 3 digit Generator


def digit_3():
    s = []
    a = random.randint(0, 9)
    b = random.randint(0, 9)
    c = random.randint(0, 9)
    s.append(a)
    s.append(b)
    s.append(c)
    print(format, "Random {0:2}")
    print((i), end="")
    print(s)
    s.sort()
    print("Sorted", end="")
    print(end="  ")
    print(s)
    return s

    # 4 digit Generator


def digit_4():
    s = []
    a = random.randint(0, 9)
    b = random.randint(0, 9)
    c = random.randint(0, 9)
    d = random.randint(0, 9)
    s.append(a)
    s.append(b)
    s.append(c)
    s.append(d)
    print("Random ", end="")
    print((i), end="")
    print(s)
    s.sort()
    print("Sorted", end="")
    print(end="  ")
    print(s)
    return s

    # Begin Generator


gentype = str(input("Enter '3' for 3-digit, '4' for 4-digit, 'm' for Megamillion or 'all' for all three"))

x = int(input("Enter a number "))
x = x + 1
if gentype == '3':
    for i in range(1, x):
        digit_3()
elif gentype == '4':
    for i in range(1, x):
        digit_4()
else:
    start = int(input("Enter smallest number to generate "))
    finish = int(input("Enter highest number to generate "))
    for i in range(1, x):
        mega()
```

**And here's the error msg:**

> ```
> line 1, in <module>
>     import random
> line 5, in <module>
>     a=random.randint(1,70)
> AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
> ```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One guess is that you have a personal module called 'random' that is in the path when you run pycharm in normal mode but not when you run idle or pycharm in debug mode.  I don't know pycharm or why the two modes would differ.

Comment: Interesting. The only file I could find in a pycharm folder was a file called "random_generator.py" I wonder if that could be the issue. I started rewriting parts of the program in pycharm...so far it works without issues. Thanks for the response.